# Want to make a custom shape using CSS

Tags: css

[image]

I want to create a shape like this and every block should be a div so that I can show info on that. I tried but I only make out the lower cone by using the below code:

```
#cone {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 70px solid transparent;
  border-right: 70px solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid red;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

How will I achieve the upper curved boxes any lead or tutorial will be great help.

Comment: Canvas might be more maintainable

Comment: @DanielA.White I never use canvas, I am going to search canvas on internet, if you can provide a reference link it will be great.

Comment: Look into CSS Shapes http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/. Other alternatives are crazy hacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the image provided as a background image and then position the div's over each square. Something like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="row1el1" class="row1">This is some text</div>
    <div id="row2el1" class="row2">This is some text</div>
    <div id="row2el2" class="row2">This is some text</div>
    <div id="row3el1" class="row3">This is some text</div>
    <div id="row3el2" class="row3">This is some text</div>
    <div id="row3el3" class="row3">This is some text</div>
    <div id="row3el4" class="row3">This is some text</div>
    <div id="row4el1" class="row4">This is some text</div>
    <div id="row4el2" class="row4">This is some text</div>
    <div id="row4el3" class="row4">This is some text</div>
    <div id="row4el4" class="row4">This is some text</div>
    <div id="row4el5" class="row4">This is some text</div>
    <div id="row4el6" class="row4">This is some text</div>
    <div id="row4el7" class="row4">This is some text</div>
    <div id="row4el8" class="row4">This is some text</div>
</div>

<style>
    #wrapper {
        position: relative;
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
        background-image: url(shapes.png);
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
    #wrapper div {
        height: 15%;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .row1 {
        width: 20%;
    }
    .row2 {
        width: 20%;
    }
    .row3 {
        width: 15%;
    }
    .row4 {
        width: 12%;
    }
    #row1el1 {
        left: 40%;
        top: 75%;
    }
    #row2el1 {
        transform: rotate(-20deg);
        left: 30%;
        top: 53%;
    }
    #row2el2 {
        transform: rotate(20deg);
        left: 50%;
        top: 53%;
    }
    #row3el1 {
        transform: rotate(-30deg);
        left: 18%;
        top: 37%;
    }
    #row3el2 {
        transform: rotate(-15deg);
        left: 34%;
        top: 30%;
    }
    #row3el3 {
        transform: rotate(15deg);
        left: 51%;
        top: 30%;
    }
    #row3el4 {
        transform: rotate(30deg);
        left: 67%;
        top: 37%;
    }
    #row4el1 {
        transform: rotate(-35deg);
        left: 3%;
        top: 20%;
    }
    #row4el2 {
        transform: rotate(-27deg);
        left: 14%;
        top: 12%;
    }
    #row4el3 {
        transform: rotate(-18deg);
        left: 25%;
        top: 7%;
    }
    #row4el4 {
        transform: rotate(-7deg);
        left: 38%;
        top: 3%;
    }
    #row4el5 {
        transform: rotate(7deg);
        left: 50%;
        top: 3%;
    }
    #row4el6 {
        transform: rotate(18deg);
        left: 62%;
        top: 7%;
    }
    #row4el7 {
        transform: rotate(27deg);
        left: 73%;
        top: 12%;
    }
    #row4el8 {
        transform: rotate(35deg);
        left: 83%;
        top: 20%;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: is this approach responsive? I will try and let you know.

Comment: its semi-responsive since the positions and dimensions of the divs are based on percentages (you can put this in a page and change the width and height of wrapper and see that everything is still in place) but to make it fully responsive you would need to change the font sizes when the wrapper is below a certain size

Comment: yeah that is good, I just made the wrapper width in percentage and working good. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make it in CSS3

```css
.wifi {
  padding: 20px;
}

.wifi,
.wifi:before {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 60px double transparent;
  border-top-color: currentColor;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.wifi:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wifi" /></div>
```

Comment: This is nice but I want div boxes so I can show the info in them. You are just putting one div. But it is nice work.